# Firestore adding Data to Doc in order

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to use a cloud function that adds an element to an existing document. The difficulty I have is that the element on the document should be ordered by one value.

Example:
doc:

- ..., Anna: 12,Katarina: 22,Markus: 23,...

New element(Josh: 18)

Doc:

- ..., Anna: 12,Josh: 18,Katarina: 22,Markus: 23,...

I already tried using an array, but then I have to overwrite the whole data of the doc every time I want to add something.

Comment: Could you pls explain a little bit more how you database structure looks like? Maybe with an example before adding and after adding an element. How it should behave and how it behaves now.

Answer (score 0):

Using an object map does not guarantee the order of items, nor does an array.
To update items in an array, you must remove the old value and add the new one with the following where the string value can also be substituted with an object if desired.

Do note that this does impact your key name limits in a firestore document, for this reason, I recommend stringifying the data in a consistent structure.

```js
var washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
    regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
});

// Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
    regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove("east_coast")
});
```

As for the order, there is no guarantee that the items will be in order and this kind of sorting is purely cosmetic to a database, of which you will have to decide how you want to sort it. This can be done with a millisecond timestamp or other incremental means.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still see a problem in that. In my case the doc will not often update, but there will be a lot of reads and I would like to optimize the search in this doc. If I add the whole array in every case I update the doc the order should be guaranteed in the way I uploaded the array or not?

Comment: there is no guarantee, which is why you will want to use a timestamp in the value so you can order by on the client. by default, most values are also sorted in the firebase console as alpha-numeric and the actual order is irrelevant to a database.

Comment: From where do you get the information that there is no guarantee for the order? In this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612101/sort-order-in-firestore-arrays) they say different.

Comment: it's not as simple as "it keeps the order of elements as they are added" if you read the specific wording, it sorts it by the objects first element then length, which could be the name, age, etc. hence - no guarantee it is in an order that is useful to you. which is why I suggested adding a timestamp as a type of index to maintain a specific order.