# Firebase Query filtering not allowing different fields for whereField and orderBy

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In essence, what I am doing is similar to snapchat stories. That said, I am creating a document for each story under the same collection "Stories". The problems begin in that I need to be able to request stories by different fields at the same time.

Ex. of story data model:

```
struct StoryModel: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var isLive: Bool?
    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var isPrivate: Bool?
    var userIDsJoined: [String]?
    var userIDsWatching: [String]?
    var startDate: Date?
    var endDate: Date?
    var hostInfoRef: DocumentReference?
}
```

I want to be able to do a whereField on isLive, but also sortBy userIDsWatching in the same query. How can I still do this sort of query:

```
Firestore.firestore()
    .collection("Stories")
    .whereField("isLive", isEqualTo: true)
    .order(by: "userIDsWatching", descending: true)
    .limitTo(5)
```

This query is invalid, see this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) on why.

My only alternative is to create a separate collection to store stories in that are live and move them to "Stories" collection when isLive is false.

Comment: Are you actually trying to ask if there is an alternative solution?  What you have is a question asking for an opinion where the possible answers are either yes or no.  The "best" might not be possible us to discern, because we don't know other factors that might affect your design, including other queries you might want to do with other fields.

Comment: Im asking if this is the best solution given my title 'Firebase Query filtering not allowing different fields for whereField and sortBy'. And other queries are irrelevant to my question, hence "specific problem".

Comment: That said, it's still a yes/no question asking for an opinion.  I think you'll have to qualify how you measure "best" in this case, and ask if there are better solutions than the one you have now that beat the specific criteria you're using. In other words: what would make an alternative objectively better than what you have now, leaving no room for opinion?

Comment: I will add that if you are actually looking for an opinion or general discussion, you're better off posting to Reddit, which allows for such things.  Stack Overflow doesn't allow appeals to opinion.

Comment: @DougStevenson will make an edit for clarity, and yes this sort of question is probably more suited for reddit.

Comment: So, to be clear, you are asking how to be able to make a query against a single collection despite the limitations of Firestore, and you are not willing to accept an answer that involves duplicating data into another collection?

Comment: Also I am unclear how you expect sorting to work on an array type field.  Is the sort order as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54778437) exactly what you want?  That seems not terribly useful.  What is the behavior of the sort that you need here?

Comment: Hey @Trevor. What isn't working about the code you shared? Is there an error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The example query i gave is invalid, you cannot use whereField and sortBy on different fields. See edit for firebase doc link

Comment: @DougStevenson I assumed sort on an array of fields would return the docs in order of fields count in each array. Which apparently is not true, hence your link. Im beginning to think my entire approach here is unsaveable. I may take this post down and create a new one based on how I will need to sort.

Comment: So: does it not compile? Or is there a runtime error? And in either case, what is the error message? Also: please don't take this post down after a long thread of comments, as a new post about the same problem will just lose that context.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen im working on a new solution and will link any questions to it here in the future. Everything complies and runs without errors, i just dont get any data back since the query is invalid. Typically you would get an error on the query call itself, but for some reason there is not one in this particular case.

Comment: I am with @DougStevenson comment. Sorting data by an array isn't a function `var userIDsWatching: [String]?` and then `.order(by: "userIDsWatching", descending: true)`. I see your followup comment but it's unclear. The initial question states you want to sort by different fields - that's easily done using a [Compound Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries). Perhaps if you can update the *question* with an example of what you're trying to do we could provide a solution (instead of guessing, which is whats happened so far)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Mises I was pointed in a better direction and finally got an error to print. The error was "Listen for query at Stories failed: The query requires an index. You can create it here..."

The solution to my problem was to:

1. create a new field in StoryModel such as "totalViewing: Int?"
2. Create an index for the Stories collection

The first fix was because orderBy on an field array returns values like this: [sort and order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612101/sort-order-in-firestore-arrays/54778437#54778437)
I thought orderBy on a field like "userIDsWatching" would order them by the document with the largest amount of values in an array. This is wrong according to the above link @Doug Stevenson provided.

The second fix was something I was unaware you can even do. I created an index and now by running this query it works as it should.

```
Firestore.firestore()
    .collection("Stories")
    .whereField("isLive", isEqualTo: true)
    .order(by: "totalViewing", descending: true)
    .limit(to: 5)
```

Between those two changes I have found a way to orderBy one field and do whereField on a completely different field.

Comment: For clarity, you are not using an `orderBy` on a *field array* - `orderBy` in the question tells Firebase to return the *documents* in the Stories collection ordered by an array. If you think about it the logic doesn't work. How would Firebase know what field to order by with multiple elements in the array? Also, index's are generally created for you; errors really only happen with a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map to an existing index. Your updated query isn't a compound query; it's a 'simple' query. Glad it works but just wanted to present that for future reference.

Comment: @Jay per my answer, the link explains how orderBy works on field arrays. I thought it was by array count, but its not. hence the switch to "totalViewing". And you cannot do a different field where and order without manually creating the index, this is not automatic. A simple query works right out of the box, such as where and order by on the same field.

Comment: Ah, yes, switching to a totalViewing field makes more sense and requires an index. Thanks for the clarification. The query about sorting on the array lead to some confusion as to what the intent was. Still not clear but using totalViewing certainly simplifies it.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, you have an error: "You cannot use `whereField` and `sortBy` on different fields." Firestore queries with `sortBy` method need to have first `whereField` method same as `sortBy` method.

So you can write code like this:

```js
Firestore.firestore()
    .collection("Stories")
    .whereField("created") // it cannot be boolean value same as array like you have in userIdsWatching field.
    .sortBy("created", descending: true)
    .limitTo(5)
```

Or I'm pretty sure it can work like that:

```js
Firestore.firestore()
    .collection("Stories")
    .whereField("created") // This line has to be first, because of you sort by it.
    .whereField("isLive", isEqualTo: true)
    .sortBy("created", descending: true)
    .limitTo(5)
```

In the second example, important might be the order of `.whereFields` functions. First need to be same as in `sortBy` method. Before you start to learn programming, learn how to read with understanding text. Your error exactly says what you have wrong in code.

And Firestore are not filtering anything. Firestore just pick and sorts documents from database. Filtering word is not correct that why you have `whereField` method, no `filterByField` method.

I found one thing. Did you know that examples in swift are different from yours?

```js
citiesRef
    .whereField("population", isGreaterThan: 100000)
    .order(by: "population") // this line is diferent same as bellow
    .limit(to: 2)
```

Comment: "You cannot use whereField and sortBy on different fields." is not an error. That is my brief explanation of whats going wrong. I am not getting any errors printed out. And in your example, you have userIDsWatching paired with an equality test. But that will not work since userIDsWatching is an array of String. Im a bit confused if that was intentional or not? Will an equality test on an array always return true if its not empty?

Comment: @Trevor I am not a Swift programmer. I just gave you a hint what you might have wrong.

Comment: On second read it appears you have mixed up my example query of what I want to do. Hence the equality query on userIDsWatching. Regardless I replaced that line with an array contains query and it still does not work. Error is: "Listen for query at Stories failed: The query requires an index. You can create it here..."

Comment: @Trevor If you want to sort by how many users are watching, just count them and create a field like `usersWatching` where it is a number no array.

Comment: That is a good suggestion and I will probably do that. However, it still is an invalid query. As shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: @Trevor Delete this question when you finish working on that topic. I think it won't help anyone except you.

Comment: Yes, I physically wrote it instead of copying form my project, edited to be exact as my project.